# Why does my then() never get invoked whenever I add a stream to my stream controller?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a bloc which has a stream controller and in the constructor of the bloc I add the stream to the controller. I wait until the stream is added and then I add a listener to it. But the then() never get's invoked. I'm sure that GeoLocator() code works because I had it in a stateful widget before and that worked like a charm but I decided to move the business logic to a bloc.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LocationBloc {
  final Geolocator _geolocator = Geolocator();
  final LocationOptions _locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10);
  StreamController<Position> _positionStreamController = StreamController<Position>();
  double _speed = 0;

  double get speed => _speed;

  LocationBloc() {
    print('it gets here');
    final Stream<Position> positionStream = _geolocator.getPositionStream(_locationOptions);
    print('and here');
    _positionStreamController.addStream(positionStream).then((value) {
      print('it never gets here');
      print(value);
      _positionStreamController.stream.listen((Position position) {
        this._speed = position == null ? 0 : position.speed;
      });
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    print('dispose location stream');
    _positionStreamController.close();
    _speed = 0;
  }
}
```

When I dispose of he bloc provider when the widget get's disposed and call the dispose in the bloc it throws the following error

```
Bad state: Cannot add event while adding a stream
```

The stateless widget

```
class DigitalSpeedMeter extends StatelessWidget {

  static Widget create(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      create: (_) => LocationBloc(),
      child: DigitalSpeedMeter(),
      dispose: (BuildContext context, LocationBloc bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: your `positionStream` seems to be active all the time so `then()` never fires

Comment: ooo wait then() doesn't fire when the stream is added? How could I add a event once the stream is added to the stream controller?

Comment: no, no, no - docs say: *"Returns a future which completes when the source stream is done."*

Comment: and if you want to add all events from some stream and still to add your own events i would use `someStream.listen(controller.add); controller.add(extraEvent);`

Comment: I see this just now. I ended up mapping the stream to a double and using a stream builder. Might be the better solution right?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LocationBloc {
  final Geolocator _geolocator = Geolocator();
  final LocationOptions _locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10);
  StreamController<double> _streamController = StreamController<double>();
  Stream<double> get stream => _streamController.stream;

  LocationBloc() {
    _streamController.addStream(_geolocator.getPositionStream(_locationOptions).map((position) => position.speed ?? 0.0));
  }

  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

With a stream builder widget.